# predict function with lasso regression

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to implement lasso regression for my sales prediction problem. I am using `glmnet` package and `cv.glmnet` function to train the model.

```
library(glmnet)
set.seed(123)
model = cv.glmnet(as.matrix(x = train[, -which(names(train) %in% "Sales")]),
                  y = train$Sales,
                  alpha = 1,
                  lambda = 10^seq(4,-1,-0.1))
best_lambda = model$lambda.min
lasso_predictions_valid <- predict(model,s = best_lambda,type = "coefficients")
```

After I read few articles about implementing lasso regression I still don't know how to add my test data on which I want to apply the prediction. There is `newx` argument to be added to predict function that I do not know also. I mean in most regression types we have newdata or data argument that we fill our test data to it.

Comment: The `newx` argument works like `newdata`. From the help page: "`newx `- Matrix of new values for x at which predictions are to be made. Must be a matrix [...]"

Comment: ok I have used this code and it worked `lasso_predictions_valid <- predict(model,s = best_lambda,newx = as.matrix(valid$Sales), type = "coefficients")` but now it gives and error in the dimensions when I want to calculate `RMSE RMSE(lasso_predictions_valid, as.matrix(valid$Sales))`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in your `lasso_predictions_valid`, you shouldn't put `valid$sales` as your newx, as I believe this is the actual sales number.

Once you have created the model with the train set, then for `newx` you need to pass matrix values of x that you want to make predictions on, I guess in this case it will be your validation set.

Looking at your example code above, I think your `predict` line should be something like:

```
lasso_predictions_valid <- predict(model, s = best_lambda, 
                                   newx = as.matrix(valid[, -which(names(valid) %in% "Sales")]), 
                                   type = "coefficients")
```

Then you should run your `RMSE()` line:

```
RMSE(lasso_predictions_valid, valid$Sales)
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I ran the RMSE line I got this error `Error in eval(call, parent.frame()) : 
  dims [product 44] do not match the length of object [856]`

Comment: You should check `length` of the two parameters in `RMSE` line. It sounds like you have different number of forecast and observed.

Comment: It is correct I have used the same syntax for other prediction models and it works. I think the problem here maybe has to do with as.matrix?

Comment: I suggest you including sample of your dataset for others to reproduce the error. If you believe there is a problem with as.matrix then I am guessing it might be due to factor variables. Do you have any categorical variable in your data? If you do, then `model.matrix` should do, e.g. `model.matrix ( ~ . -1, data)`